# Using OR on hive ParseException

Tags: oracle, join, hiveql

so I am trying to transfer ddl from odi (oracle data integration) into hive.

The code looks like this:

```
(308 row of code, there are fppnonday, dtddyr subquery before )
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM dffo
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND dffo.date = '20100909')dffot 
ON fppnonday.B_ACCT = dffot.B_CODE
where ( from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dffot.START_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dffot.END_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND (dffot.C_CODE = '000' OR dffot.NAG = 'Y'))

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM  dflagw
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND dflagw.date = '20100909')dflagwr
ON fppnonday.CUER = dflagwr.CER
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dflagwr.START_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dflagwr.END_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd')) > dtddyr.FULL_DATE
;
```

When I run all the query, the Error occurs:
ParseException: Missing EOF at LEFT near ')' It refers to 2nd LEFT OUTER JOIN

What went wrong? How to use OR effectively and efficient?

Any ideas/helps always be appreciated!

Comment: 1. `LEFT JOIN -> WHERE -> LEFT JOIN` => `LEFT JOIN -> LEFT JOIN -> WHERE`
2. WHERE condition (like dffot.C_CODE = '000') that acceses outer table makes it INNER JOIN

Comment: Sorry, i dont get it, Lucas.

Comment: Query has an order `SELECT FROM LEFT JOIN LEFT JOIN WHERE` and in your query you have `SELECT FROM LEFT JOIN  WHERE LEFT JOIN` which is incorrect syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AND` instead of `WHERE` so that you can combine those conditions into the `ON` condition:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM dffo
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND dffo.date = '20100909')dffot 
ON (fppnonday.B_ACCT = dffot.B_CODE)
AND ( from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dffot.START_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dffot.END_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND (dffot.C_CODE = '000' OR dffot.NAG = 'Y'))

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM  dflagw
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND dflagw.date = '20100909')dflagwr
ON fppnonday.CUER = dflagwr.CER
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dflagwr.START_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dflagwr.END_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd')) > dtddyr.FULL_DATE
;
```

or you can put the where statement at last, as suggested by the comments:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM dffo
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND dffo.date = '20100909')dffot 
ON fppnonday.B_ACCT = dffot.B_CODE

LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM  dflagw
    WHERE 1 = 1 
    AND dflagw.date = '20100909')dflagwr
ON fppnonday.CUER = dflagwr.CER
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dflagwr.START_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dflagwr.END_DATE, 'yyyyMMdd')) > dtddyr.FULL_DATE

where ( from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dffot.START_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(dffot.END_DATE,'yyyyMMdd')) <= dtddyr.FULL_DATE
AND (dffot.C_CODE = '000' OR dffot.NAG = 'Y'))
;
```

Comment: is the suggestion has no effects on result of query?

Comment: @thecardcaptor But all we are given is undefined code, we don't know what the asker meant by it. This answer is guessing at what output the asker wanted. The answerer especially shouldn't say "it shouldn't have any effect".